# is there any media query for desktop which can work only for 1366*768 landscape device only

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries, mpmediaquery

i have make a sence and it works only for ipad-pro (1366*1024) landscape. It dont disturb my 1366*768 device viewport. let me show the code below:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1025px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: landscape){selector{

    background-size: 100% 75% !important;
    background-position: center top  188px!important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;
    }  
}
```

now i need another media query which can work only for 1366*768. i edit the upper one for 1366*768 but it cant work. I think i help you make understand what i actually want: please help somebody!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* ----------- iPad Pro ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-height: 1366px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-height: 1366px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-height: 1366px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```

Try this and check.I don't have an iPad Pro but this works for me in the Chrome simulator.